# Working with too many PictureBoxes, any way to use a For?

Tags: vb.net

**Warning : Im completely new to VB.net and only know the most basic form of programming, maybe even less**

Visual Basic 2010 Express

I have declared an Array `Equipa(x,y) as integer.`
I have 30 PictureBoxes ( PictureBox1 to PictureBox30)
In my mind, I assigned each PictureBox to a X and Y in the Array.

At load form, I want to change the image of PictureBox5 to PictureBox25.
For this I copy pasted 20 times `PictureBox(x).Image = My.Resources.GreyHexagon`
I would like to have a Loop that can do this without me copy pasting so much.

---

During the program, clicking on PictureBox5, for example, changes it to a different image, depending on the value, of the Array declared.

```
If Equipa(0, 0) = 0 Then
            PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.GreyHexagon
        ElseIf Equipa(0, 0) = 1 Then
            PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.BlueHexagon
        Else
            PictureBox4.Image = My.Resources.RedHexagon
        End If
```

The problem, again, is I have to repeat this code, for every Array position, since each PictureBox is assigned to each position.

So what I need is  a Loop that can go through each PictureBox, I'm not asking you to make that code, I just don't know how to go through each PictureBox, for example PictureBox5 to PictureBox25.

**PS** . The following code changes EVERY PictureBox to the Image I wan't. But I do not understand any of this code, therefor can't change it to only go through PictureBox5 to PictureBox25.

```
Me.SuspendLayout()
    For Each box As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
       box.Image = My.Resources.RedHexagon2
    Next box
    Me.ResumeLayout()
```

Comment: show a snippet of your current code to make us understand your environment

Comment: The answer is "of course". Are these picture boxes embedded in a spreadsheet or are they on a userform? If the former -- use the `Shapes` collection. If the later -- use the `Controls` collection.

Comment: @John I just went to Tools and created a bunch of PictureBoxes, is that in a spreadsheet or a userform?

Comment: Since you are asking, it is in the spreadsheet (you can't inadvertently create a userform).

Comment: **@John** Sorry for asking, I am completely new to coding, does **ShapeCollection Class** have to do with what you said?

Comment: Yes -- but what do you mean by `Tools`? Did you create these shapes in the VBA editor or by using the `insert` tab on the ribbon.

Comment: **@John** I clicked ToolBox, then doubleclicked PictureBox.

Comment: A question I should have asked first: what application is this? Excel? Word? PowerPoint?

Comment: **@John** Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express. StackOverflow is suggesting we open a chat, should we? I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: We have been talking at cross-purposes. VB.Net <> VBA. They just aren't the same language. I was just noticing that VBA Excel doesn't actually have a *PictureBox* control (it has *image* controls), which is why I asked what application you were using (I am not so familiar with what might be possible with Word). I just changed the tag to the correct one for vb.net. In any event something like `Shapes("PictureBox" & i)`will probably work in a loop -- though I am not sure of the exact syntax for VB.Net.

Comment: Declare an array at the form level.  Then in form load fill it with the picturebox objects.  Now you can use it in a loop.  Nothing to do with ShapeCollection, Shapes or anything else

Comment: **@Plutonix** Declare an array As what? Does the code look something like this `Array(x) = PictureBox1` ?

Comment: You should lay off the overuse of bold.  We are able to extract the parts that are actually important better than you.  It also appears to swallow the pings sometimes because I did not get that last one.

Comment: @Plutonix I edited the main thread to be clearer. Also on my last comment I didn't understand what kind of array I declare, Integer, String? And how do I fill the array with PictureBoxes?

Comment: You keep changing the question a bit too much. The answer posted will work for the PB array as long as they are all on the form (not in different containers).   But **now** you have the issue that each call to `My.Resources.fooImg` is creating a new image.  If 10 PBs have the same image you dont need 10 distinct objects, they can show the same one, **and** you need to dispose of the old image so your app doesnt leak.  For that, I'd put the images into an array so you create just one object per image ever

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
Me.SuspendLayout()
For Each box As PictureBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()
   box.Image = SomeNewPicture
Next box
Me.ResumeLayout()
```

If you want to be able to look at specific images, you can still just say things like `PictureBox4.Image = SomeNewImage`. But if you *really* want to access them by index, first define this variable as a member of the form class:

```
Private PictureBoxes() As PictureBox
```

And then do this in your form's Load event:

```
PictureBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)().ToArray()
```

Now you can reference each PictureBox by index:

```
PictureBoxes(4).Image = SomeNewPicture
PictureBoxes(10).Image = SomeOtherNewPicture
```

You could also do something like this:

```
Me.SuspendLayout()
For i As Integer = 5 to 25
    PicturesBoxes(i) = My.Resources.RedHexagon2
Next i
Me.ResumeLayout()
```

Finally, to address the `If/Then` code in your edited question, I'd do something like this:

```
'Note this Array shorthand requires a more recent version of Visual Studio
' I used it for brevity in the response. You should be able to convert it on your own
Dim Images() As Image = {My.Resources.GreyHexagon, My.Resources.BlueHexagon, My.Resources.RedHexagon}
Dim ImageIndex As Integer = Equipa(0, 0)
If ImageIndex < 0 OrElse ImageIndex > 1 Then ImageIndex = 2
PictureBox4.Image = Images(ImageIndex)
```

Comment: What does **Me.SuspendLayout()** and **Me.ResumeLayout()?** 
The code works, it changes every picture in my form to the one I specified, but I had to change **box.Picture** to **box.Image**, but what if I didn't want to edit ALL pictureboxes?
For example if I only want to change the image of PictureBox4 to PictureBox10

Comment: You're changing 100 images. You don't want to have to redraw the form in between each one. The Suspend/ResumeLayout() calls allow you to only redraw the screen one time. It avoids flickering.

Comment: Alright that part I now understand and will use it. Now what if I don't want to change every single PictureBox, but only PictureBox4 to PictureBox10 ?

Comment: Then you can just say `PictureBox4.Image = SomeNewImage`. But if you really need to see access them via index, you can see my edit.

Comment: I couldn't make anything work, most likely my fault. I really apreciate your efforts, you gave a good answer, but in the end I will have to do everything manually.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried once before: In the declarations,
`Dim pic(29) As PictureBox`

And then in `Public Sub New`, I wrote `picarray()` and then made a `Private Sub picarray`. In this sub I dimmed each picture to the  array

```
        pic(0) = picturebox1
        pic(1) = picturebox2
        pic(2) = picturebox3
        ...
        pic(29) = picturebox30
```

In my case, I wanted to move all 30 at once, and I had a timer, so I did:

`Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _Timer1.Tick
        For i = 0 To 29
            pic(i).Left = pic(i).Left + 3
        Next
End Sub`

To move them all to the right at once. I used the same way to move them back if the last one on the left hits the form's edge.

Comment: In the `For i = ...` part, "i" is only a variable, so you could change it for x or even your name, as a string